# Proving existence of solutions for second-order differential equation $u''(t)=-w^2\sin(u(t))$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $w>0$ and $$u''(t)=-w^2\sin(u(t))$$ for $t\geq 0$. 
I'd like to see that the solutions to the system exist on the whole $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ and if an initial value is given, they are supposed to be unique.

Usually I'd translate a second-order system to a first-order one, by renaming $v(t):= u''(t)$ and then rewriting it into a first-order matrix differential equation, which would be linear and therefore I'd easily be able to draw conclusions about the existence of solutions, but this does not work here, because of the $\sin()$ function.

Another approach would be to immediately try to solve by seperating variables, i.e.

$$ \int_0^t \frac{u''(s)}{\sin(u(s))}\,ds = \int_0^t -w^2 \, ds$$

but here the second order ruins the substitution ( or can you somehow integrate that? ).

I'm not looking for a solution, but a hint on how to approach these second order autonomous systems!

Comment: Surely you don't mean "renaming v(t)= u''(t)"?  If we let v(t)= u'(t), we can write that second order equation as the first order equation system, u'= v, v'= w^2 sin(u^2).  Now the fact that the solutions exist for all R is clear because those function, v and w^2 sin(u^2) are continuous for all v and u.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rewrite

$$ \begin{cases}
u''(t) = -w^2 \sin(u(t)),& t\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0};\\
u(0)=u_0; \\
u'(0)=v_0.
\end{cases}$$

as

$$ \begin{cases}
\begin{pmatrix}
u(t) \\ v(t)
\end{pmatrix}' =
\begin{pmatrix}
v(t) \\ -w^2 \sin(u(t))
\end{pmatrix}; \\
\begin{pmatrix}
u(0) \\ v(0)
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
u_0 \\ v_0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{cases} $$

by setting $v(t)=u'(t)$. Note that the function

$$F: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \  F( u, v)= (v,-w^2 \sin(u)) $$

is lipschitz (as $\sin$ has bounded derivative). Thus, by the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem our second Cauchy problem has a unique solution. As the second system is equivalent to the first one, it has a unique solution as well.

Comment: \begin{cases}
\begin{pmatrix}
u(t) \\ v(t)
\end{pmatrix}' =
\begin{pmatrix}
X  & X' \\ Y & Y'
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
u(t) \\ v(t)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{cases} 
I thought I had to bring it into above form to use the properties of linear differential equations, but I see now that there is no need for that. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: The point is, that our ODE is not linear and therefore we cannot bring it into this form. However, the reduction to a first-order system above works always :)